# Как вызвать кнопки у формы с свойством FormBorderStyle=None?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Я разрабатываю приложение на c#. Уже попробовал сделать свои кнопки и обрабатывать их нажатия. Но эти кнопки выглядят не очень красиво и я бы хотел спросить, есть ли способ вызвать кнопки отдельно, как в FormBorderStyle=Sizable. Я видел такое у google chrome, кнопки явно вызваны отдельно.

Comment: ну во первых хром написан явно не на c#...но т к GUI там построено с помощью GTK, то на c# не составит труда юзануть...вопрос в другом...что значит "вызвать отдельно"....отдельно от чего...чего конкретно вы хотите (конечная цель)?

Comment: FormBorderStyle=None убирает полностью системные кнопки (закрыть, свернуть). Я имел в виду чтобы вывести такие же кнопки, но используя форму без границ.

Comment: [How to create custom window chrome in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792677/312041)

Comment: [WPF: Нестандартное окно](https://habr.com/ru/post/158561/)

Comment: Chrome кнопки рисует сам ([код](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/ui/views/window/custom_frame_view.cc#571)) и у Вас получится :) Удачи!

Comment: @tym32167, @defaultlocale, я работаю с этим. Не могли бы вы подсказать как сделать анимацию сворачивания? Если сделать так `this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`, то окно будет просто моментально сворачиваться без анимации.

Comment: [ControlPaint.DrawCaptionButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawcaptionbutton?view=netframework-4.8) - этот метод поможет _рисовать_ нужные кнопки. Но обрабатывать их поведение нужно самому (наведение мышки, изменение состояния и пр.)

Comment: @Роман Есть способ попроще и способ посложнее: [Use windows animations on borderless form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31473489)

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо. Вы мне помогли. Я первый раз пишу на данном сайте.

Comment: @Роман Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло. Вопрос немного общий, но для первого раза неплохо. Если решили проблему можете сами опубликовать код, возможно, кому-нибудь в будущем пригодится.

Comment: @defaultlocale Да, я обязательно опубликую. Сейчас еще пишу, пробую по-разному.

Answer (score 0):

Роман. Можете вопрос раскрыть подробнее? Вы хотите сами рисовать кнопки программным способом? Если да, то бросьте сие издевательство, используйте уже встроенные возможности WPF. 
Если вы хотите делать красивые кнопки и красивый интерфейс, пользуйтесь встроенными возможностями стилизации XAML. 
В самый край, можете воспользоваться Corel Draw для создания векторной графики, с помощью Corel Draw вы можете сделать красивые элементы вашего интерфейса, но я рекомендую ознакомиться с возможностями XAML. 
Вот например [статья](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_styles.htm)
Еще одна полезная [статья](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/10.php).

Comment: У автора WinForms.